# Program which add one char to String, then show result by toString() method and count number of String by length()

Tags: java, class, methods

I have to create class with `String` and `int` fields. Constructor without arguments have to initialize: empty string and 0 value for int. `addChar(char)` method should let program to add new chars to string(name). `toString()` method should return this string and `length()` method have to show number of this chars. I tried something like this:

```
public class Word {

String name;
int number;

public Word() {

    name = "";
    number = 0;

}

public char addChar() {
  return ;
}

public String toString() {
  System.out.println(name); 
}

public int length() {
  return name.length();
  System.out.println (name.length());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
}
```

But really dont know how to write method which could add one char to String (there's error) and how to write program that could use these methods to show it all works.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a litle bit of refactoring, but here you go:

```
public class Word {

private String name;
private int number;

public Word() {
    name = "";
}

public void addChar(char ch) {
  name += ch;
  number++;
}

public String toString() {
  return name; 
}

public int length() {
  return number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Word myWord = new Word();
    myWord.addChar('H');
    System.out.println(myWord);
    myWord.addChar('e');
    myWord.addChar('l');
    myWord.addChar('l');
    myWord.addChar('o');
    System.out.println(myWord);
    System.out.println(myWord.length());

}
}
```

result:

```
H
Hello
5
```

Changes:

- method toString does return `name`.
- method length does return `number`.
- I added a small proof of concept in the main method.
- I implmented the addChar and changed the return type to void.
- I changed the Datatype of `name` to [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know it would be better but unfortunately excercise require int field :/

Comment: What is the requirement for the int field? is it the length? i can adapt the code to do that.

Comment: I guess it is. Empty string(String) = 0(int), more chars in string - number raise.

Comment: Is there any way to this without using StringBuilder method? I mean, to create constructor which initialize fields by empty string and 0?

Answer (score 2):

**-** A `String` is **Immutable**, so **you can't change it**, when ever you try to change a String actually a **new String Object is created on the heap.**

**-** Its better to use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` which are **Mutable**.

**-** `StringBuilder` came into existence from **Java 5**, which is **Not Thread-Safe**, where as `StringBuffer` exists **before** the arrival of `StringBuilder`, but its **Thread-Safe**.

**//////////////////////Edited Part///////////////////////**

Try it this way..........................

```
public class Word {

StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
int number;        // Class variable are already intialized to its initial value,
                   // in the case of int its 0.


                  // String already has an overridden toString method, so its not needed

public void addChar(String s) {

    name.append(s);
}


public String getString(){

    return name.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Word w = new Word();

    System.out.println(w.getString().length());
    w.addChar("hello");
    System.out.println(w.getString().length());
    w.addChar("Hi");
    System.out.println(w.getString().length());
 }
}
```

Comment: @Fastkowy please see my edited answer,i have posted the code, and yes its important to know the basics at the very beginning, cause that will help you to write better codes.... Thats why i gave the theory at the beginning.....

Comment: I will keep it in mind :)This excercise doesn't require StringBuilder but now I see it's a better way to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not compile for at least 2 problems: -

1. Your `toString` method is not really returning anything. Rather it is printing your string. Change your method body to return your name.
2. In your length method, you have `unreachable code`. You have a `sysout` statement after `return` statement that will never be executed.

---

Now, first you need to solve the above issues.

Then in `addChar` method, you actually need to pass a `char` as `parameter` to add to your `string`. You are missing it. Also, you don't really need to `return` the `char` that you just added. So `char` `return type` is not needed. Just `void` will be `OK`. As you already have a `toString` method to get your modified `string` back.

So, your `addChar` should look like: -

```
public void addChar(char ch) {
    name += ch;
}
```

And your modified `toString` and `length` method should be like this: -

```
public String toString() {
    return name; 
}

public int length() {
    return name.length();
}
```

Rest are all unchanged.

Comment: You could just do `name += ch`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed up some of your code for you.

Notes:

> `this("", 0)` calls the constructor that accepts a `String` and `int`.
>
> `addChar` should return nothing and just add on the character.
>
> `toString` just returns a string.

Code:

```
public class Word {
    String name;
    int number;

    public Word() {
        this("", 0);
    }

    public Word(String s) {
        this(s, 0);
    }

    public Word(String s, int i) {
        name = s;
        number = i;
    }

    public void addChar(char c) {
        name += Character.toString(c);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int length() {
        return name.length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but could you explain me where are <code>Character</code> (before .toString(c)) come from?

Comment: Its a `wrapper` class for `char`. similar to `Integer` and `Float` and other wrapper class. Google it, you will get the docs to see.